# Mysql Inj Update

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

Тестирую mysql инъекцию на своем сайте конечно же, и стало интересно, select легко делается, а можно ли сделать update через инъекцию? через get

Comment: Конечно же да. Уязвимый параметр к проведению инъекции может попасть и в конструкции Insert, Update, Delete, Replace и т.д.